# Best way to use a database view equivalent in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a working solution to this duct-taped together, but it relies on some pretty nasty queries that I'm afraid will make the application fairly brittle. Looking for advice on how to better implement the following.

I have models for Child, ChildStatus and StatusValue. The StatusValue has an 'active' flag. I want to then use this active status to filter most times that I pull children from the database (along the lines of a soft delete).

The Child model below works pretty swell for dealing with individual instances. However, it gets messy (at least the way I have done it) for pulling data in aggregate.

```
class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :child_statuses
  has_many :status_values, :through => :child_statuses

  ...

  def current_status
    child_statuses.last
  end

  def status_name
    if current_status
      current_status.status_value.name
    else
      "n/a"
    end
  end

  def status_active
    current_status && current_status.status_value.active
  end

end


class ChildStatus < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :child
  belongs_to :status_value, :foreign_key => :status_id
end


class StatusValue < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :child_statuses
end
```

With the above, when I want to pull a query of children in an active status, I end up with a big raw SQL query with bits like `...AND child_statuses.created_at = (SELECT MAX(created_at) FROM child_statuses WHERE child_id = children.id)`

I feel like I'm falling back to my SQL comfort zone, but there is probably a better way to do this.

Shouldn't I be able to do something like `Child.where(:status_value.active => "TRUE")` ? (This throws an error - undefined method 'active' for :status_value:Symbol)

Any guidance is greatly appreciated. I have thought of exploring a database view to make it work also, but I'm not convinced that it will help.

Answer (score 3):

You can create the database view (use `execute "CREATE VIEW my_view AS..."` in your migration) and point an ActiveRecord model at it instead of at a table.

```
class MyView < ActiveRecord::Base
  def readonly?
    true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `Child.includes(:status_values).where('status_values.active = true')`?

*Disclaimer:* I'm not clear on the difference between `Child.joins()` and `Child.includes()`.

Comment: I was able to get some variations to work, such as `Child.joins(:sponsor).where('sponsors.facility_id' => 7).joins(:child_statuses => :status_value).where(:status_values => {:active => :TRUE})`. However, the real struggle is getting it to group by child and only take most recent (`MAX(id)`) from child_statuses.